# How to remove double field entries?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL DB with 7000+ Records. IN one field (link_to_pdf) at few records  I have field dublicates in it: F.e.

A#13#10B#13#10C#13#10**A**#13#10**B**

Each field entry is separated by CR/LF. (here #13#10)

How can I remove the doubles in the field my a MySQL Procedure? (the bold in the example above)

Thanks a lot
Walter

Comment: Sorry that doesn't look like a link at all (as the name would suggest) you could give a more concrete example on how it looks? This does look like the field contains multiple data points? If so you would have to read it, split it, look for duplicates and remove them. What have you tried to make it work? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Seth, thanks I have done it in Delphi. The A is just a dummy for a link, the real link is like file://v:\mypdf.pdf I thought it can be done without delphi just as a MySQL Function.

Comment: Well you probably can, it's just not going to be pretty as usually a field that contains multiple values isn't properly normalized to begin with. You would have to use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two) and pretty much apply the same kind of logic. Nice that you did find a solution and posted it.

Comment: @Seth thanks for the link, Yes but this is Endnote, where the links_to_pdf are all in one field. It was not my idea but I had to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
     procedure TForm1.Button28Click(Sender: TObject);
     var
        pdfs: string;
     begin
        UniConnection1.Loginprompt:=true;
        UniScript_cr_linknames.Execute;
        uniquery8.Execute;

        uniquery9.sql.text:='Select * from refs order by id asc;';
        uniquery9.execute;
        while not(uniquery9.eof) do
           begin
           uniquery11.sql.text:='Select * from linknames where id = :vonid group by linkname order by linkname; ';
           uniquery11.parambyname('vonid').asinteger:=uniquery9.fieldbyname('id').asinteger;
           uniquery11.execute;
           pdfs:='';
           while not(uniquery11.eof) do
              begin
              if pdfs='' then
                 pdfs:=uniquery11.fieldbyname('linkname').asstring
              else
                 pdfs:=pdfs+#13#10+   uniquery11.fieldbyname('linkname').asstring;

              //if uniquery11.RecordCount > 1 then ShowMessage(format('Update refs set link_to_pdf = %s where id=%d;',[pdfs,uniquery9.fieldbyname('id').asinteger]));

              uniquery11.Next;   
              end;

           uniquery10.sql.text:='Update refs set link_to_pdf = :links where id=:vonid;';
           uniquery10.parambyname('links').asstring:=pdfs;
           uniquery10.parambyname('vonid').asinteger:=uniquery9.fieldbyname('id').asinteger;
           uniquery10.execute;
           if Pos(#13,pdfs)> 0 then WriteLOgMemo(Format('UPD: Id: %d done with more than one unique-LINK ) :',[uniquery9.fieldbyname('id').asinteger]));

           uniquery9.next;
           end;

           end;
```

wherby the Query8 and the Script look like this:

```
     insert into linknames (id,linkname)
     (SELECT
       refs.id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(refs.link_to_pdf, '\n', numbers.n), '\n', -1) link_to_pdf
     FROM
       numbers INNER JOIN refs
       ON CHAR_LENGTH(refs.link_to_pdf)
          -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(refs.link_to_pdf, '\n', ''))>=numbers.n-1
     ORDER BY
       id, n)
```

numbers table just a table with numbers:

```
     CREATE TABLE `numbers` (
       `n` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
       `recnum` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       PRIMARY KEY (`recnum`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```